# Menu Data Population using BackBone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I need to make a menu where i have one button when i click on that menu a list of main categories displayed and when mouse over on this main categories it should display its sub categories
Like this

```
Categories>
Books>Book1
     >Book2
Electronics>TV1
           >TV2
```

using backbone.js and underscore.js. Now i am able to show the main categories like Books, Electronics etc. But i not able to populate corresponding sub category. How do i display this menu in this format?

Comment: Please, provide some source code.

Comment: @kharandziuk could you please provide me some example on JSfiddle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Menu Button display with main and sub categories using backbone.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270322/menu-button-display-with-main-and-sub-categories-using-backbone-js)