# Menu Button display with main and sub categories using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have  a menu button where i have render main categories and on mouse over need to render its subcategories.Now i am able to render the main categories but not subcategories.

This is my View.

```
 var Product_View = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: 'div',
                className: 'products',
                initialize: function (options) {
                    this.options = options || {};
                },
                events: {
                    "mouseover #category_menu" : "test"
                },
                test: function(){
                    alert('here...');
                   //need to add code to render the sub categories here
                },
                render: function() {
                    _.templateSettings = 
                        {
                            evaluate:    /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
                            interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g
                        };
                  var compiled = _.template(this.options.temp);   
         document.getElementById(this.options.target).innerHTML=compiled({model:this.model.toJSON()});
                  return this;
                }

        });
```

here i am calling render method to list main category

```
  var category_menu = new Models.ProductView({
                    model : itemcollection,
                    temp : template,
                    target : "category_menu"
                });

                category_menu.render();
```

and tender template is like this

```
{{ _.each(model, function(item) { }}
<a href="#" id="{{=item.name}}">{{=item.name}}
{{ });}}
```

now i am getting main categories but not able to render subcategories

Comment: Where you have stored subcategories? It's an attribute of a model or something else?

Comment: asked the same question twice ?

Comment: 1. Just hard-code the menu in the template    2. Create a model, iterate over it and create sub-menus (not-recommended)